# How build 32 bit app with VStudio 2013 on Win7 64-bit?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, 32bit-64bit

I am trying to build a 32 bit EXE on a Win7 64-bit system using MS Visual Studio 2013 and BAT files, not from within the GUI.

According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f2ccy3wt(v=vs.120).aspx, all that needs to be done is run VCVARSALL with the "x86" option.  That is supposed to set up a bunch of environment variables that cause the tools to emit 32 bit code.  When I do that, everything completes without errors.  The resulting EXE runs correctly on a 64 bit system.  On a WinXP 32-bit system a window pops up saying that it's not a valid 32 bit application.

I have put all this into a BAT file to show exactly what I'm doing.  This BAT file deletes all derived files to make sure that they actually get built and are not just lying around from previous attempts.  It also sets the relevant environment variables (that I know of) before VCVARSALL to make sure there isn't some strange previous setup that VCVARSALL doesn't quite deal with.

Here is the BAT file:

```
@echo off
rem
rem   Test of building a 32 bit executable.
rem
rem   See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f2ccy3wt(v=vs.120).aspx
rem
setlocal
if exist hello.exe del hello.exe
if exist hello.exp del hello.exp
if exist hello.lib del hello.lib
if exist hello.obj del hello.obj

set include=
set lib=
set libpath=
set VS120COMNTOOLS=
set vstudio=
set PATH=C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem

call "%MSVCDir%\vcvarsall" x86

cl /c hello.c /Fohello.obj
link /out:hello.exe /incremental:no hello.obj
```

Again, the result is HELLO.EXE that runs fine on this system, but not on a 32 bit system.

How do I build a 32 bit EXE on this 64 bit system?

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with the bitness, VS2013 by default builds programs that require Vista or higher.  A side-effect of the linker's /SUBSYSTEM setting.  You must also target an older version of the SDK, 7.1 or less.  Most easily done in VS2013 with the IDE, change the Platform toolset setting to v120_xp.

Comment: @Hans: Intereseting.  I have various things to build automatically, so doing it within the IDE doesn't work for me.  I'll look up /SUBSYSTEM.  Where do I look to find how to set things up for the older SDK?  Does that even come with VS2013?  I have automated processes that build various things on WinXP systems, but need to make them work on a Win7 system with VS2013.  The result still needs to support older WinXP systems.

Comment: Use MSBuild.exe to build automatically.  If you insist on hoofing it by hand then look at the .tlog files or the detailed build trace, they show the compiler and linker options that are used when you change the platform toolset.  The compiler's /I (include directories) and the linker's /SUBSYSTEM options are what matter.

Comment: @Hans: I already have many scripts and other parts of a larger build system that all works fine on WinXP.  Due to computer upgrade, I need to get this working on Win7 64-bit with VS2013.  There are reasons for all this, some historic, but also that various things other than Windows executables are being built that have nothing to do with VS.